# Can not play sound in Sony WH-H910N ( Bluetooth Headphone )

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones, sony

I recently bought `Sony WH-H910N` and I try to play sound in my headphone with Bluetooth in `Ubuntu 20.04` but I failed, I tried many posts available in `askubuntu` about

1. How to connect sony wh1000xm3/4 into ubuntu
2. No Sound in ubuntu 20.04
3. Headset not found in Bluetooth devices ubuntu 20.04

and many more, my whole google search related to bluetooth and sound is purple now.

I also noticed a strange thing that if I connect it using my mobile it's showing `WH-H910N(h.ear)` but in ubuntu it's showing `LE_WH-H910N(h.ear)`.

[image]

[image]

It successfully paired every time but no headphone dropdown shows in sound setting and no headset icon available when clicking on connected in Bluetooth search.

I am trying to connect it since 3 days and no luck, please help

Product: https://www.sony.co.in/electronics/headband-headphones/wh-h910n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very stupid mistake that I have done in my life.

When you first time connects with Bluetooth then you will see `WH-H910N(h.ear)` but after that, if you want to connect it with another device Just press the power off button for `7-10` seconds and you will hear Bluetooth pairing on and you will see the Bluetooth headphone device found in your Bluetooth searching devices.

I installed/upgrade/degrade many libraries to connect my headphone but after my stupid mistake, I connect it with native Bluetooth provided by ubuntu itself.

I answered this question because no one will do it this mistake in the future.

THANKS

Comment: It must really be stupid indeed... LOL! Just joking.

Comment: Same stupid problem, same stupid obvious solution

Comment: thank you ! )))